# make a call answer

Tags: android

I would like to make phone calls from my app.
I m using that code:

```
 private void call7() {
        try {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:281212114"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("CALL", "Call failed", e);
        }
    }
```

my question is, how could i just have the phone number in my call view but make the call only when the user press the call button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `ACTION_DIAL` instead of `ACTION_CALL` when you build your intent call.

Answer (score 1):

Use ACTION_VIEW instead of ACTION_CALL. See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html